# Testing a capacitor with a nodeMUC Lolin V3

Tags: esp8266, clones, capacitors

Apparently it's possible to [test the capacitance of a capacitor](http://www.circuitbasics.com/how-to-make-an-arduino-capacitance-meter/) with an arduino. In this [thread](https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=160&t=16566), someone tries to do the same on a NodeMCU but the conclusion is that it's enough to get the change in capacitantce, not the real value, and it's not "really stable" (reliable?).

I would like to get the real value of the capacitance (not just the change of the capacitance). Is there a way to do it with a [NodeMCU Lolin v3](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/V2-4M-4FLASH-NodeMcu-Lua-WIFI-Networking-development-board-Based-ESP8266/32647690484.html?spm=0.8937489.0.0.2aee2e0elybUZR)?
If yes, how?
If no, will an arduino clone (like Elegoo or Geekcreit) be precise enough to give a real value of the capacitance?

Comment: An arduino uno has a high current output for a digital output pin and a high impedance analog input. The nodemcu has neither. An arduino uno clone is okay. Try a few examples that you can find. Some are accurate for small capacitance values, such as 100pF. You can start with this good example: https://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=12075 Please tell us what this is for. If you want to measure the soil moisture with a capacitance meter, then I think this is the wrong way.

Comment: Thanks for the link, this is a very good example. I just want to be able to test my capacitors, to see if they are working and to get their capacitance value.

Comment: And by the way, I have seen this [3€ arduino uno](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/high-quality-One-set-UNO-R3-CH340G-MEGA328P-for-Arduino-UNO-R3-NO-USB-CABLE/32697443734.html), do you think it will be precise enough for testing capacitors.

Comment: Yes, that will work. You need an extra driver for the ch340g usb serial chip.